# How to seperate values in a csv column to use as multivalent feature column in sparse_column_with_integerized_feature in tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I'm just using Tensorflow and its tf.learn api to create and train a DNNRegressor model. I have an integer feature column that is multivalent (I can have more that one integer value in that column for each row) and I use tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_integerized_feature for this feature column.

now my problem is how I should seperate integers in that column in the csv file. I use ',' but I got this error:

```
'Value passed to parameter 'x' has DataType string not in list of allowed 
  values: int32, int64, float32, float64'.
```

this is the line of code that creates the sparse feature column:

```
    userWatchIds = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_integerized_feature("userWatchIds", combiner='mean', bucket_size=166000)
```

userWatchIds is the name of multivalent Integer column in csv file]

I really appreciate your help

Comment: How did you seperate the intergers? Can you provide the code?

Comment: I seperate Integers with ',' in csv column but It seems that is not the right format. in other words 'userWatchIds' is the name of the column that has multivalent Integer values that I seperate them with ',' in csv now and I got error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the input like "category1, category2, category3" format can be directly used as multivalent input to tf.